# Tensor dimension manipulation in python

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, tensor

I have a question about how one could manipulate a tensor in python. Consider a (T,n,p) tensor generated from a normal distribution (each element)

```
import numpy as np
X         = np.random.normal(0,1,(self.T,self.n,self.p))
```

where you can think of `T` as the time dimension, `n` as the "cross-sectional" dimension and `p` as the variable dimension. My question is how could on reshape the tensor such that n and T change places while keeping the structure. By keeping the structure, I mean that element (T,n,p) would correspond to element (n,T,p) when reshaping.

Here is an example:

```
X = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
              [[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])

X_reshape = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
                       [10, 11, 12]],
                       
                      [[ 4,  5,  6],
                       [13, 14, 15]],
                 
                      [[ 7,  8,  9],
                       [16, 17, 18]]])
```

I hope i was clear. Thanks for any help ^_^

Y

Comment: You may be looking for `X.swapaxes(0, 1)`.

Comment: thanks, this helps!